# Find the next two terms in this sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first five numbers of the sequence are the following ones:

1, 2, 6, 15, 31, ..., ...

Target:
What I would like to know is the general formula of the sequence.

Solution:
The numbers are 56 and 92.

Comment: Notice the pattern of differences.

Comment: In order to make this problem well-posed, you need to add additional constraints. For every choice of the next two terms, there exists a polynomial of degree at most six which perfectly [interpolates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) the given sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(n+1)^\text{th}$ term of the sequence is given by:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(n+2)(2n^2-n+3)}{6}. 
\end{equation}

This is sequence number A056520 on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (see http://oeis.org/A056520).

Comment: What do you mean by (n+1)th term ? So if I want to find the 7th term I have to substitute n by 6?

Comment: @Anne That's right!

Comment: @Anne By the way, I encourage you to take a look at the OEIS (I left a link in my answer) - its a fantastic resource full of many beautiful sequences and combinatorial descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** The sequence is given by $a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)^2$